# Restoring sessions in Deezer iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, deezer

I am using [Deezer iOS SDK](https://developers.deezer.com/sdk/ios), in Swift so far everything is going well except the session, in Android SDK a method `.restoreSession()` exists to avoid popup user login every time, but I can't see it in iOS SDK , so every time session gets expired, users get popup to login again with hi's Deezer account, anyway to save or restore session in iOS SDK?

This is the Android restore session code:

```
// restore any saved session
SessionStore sessionStore = new SessionStore();
if (sessionStore.restore(deezerConnect, context)) {
    // The restored session is valid, navigate to the Home Activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

is it possible to do this in iOS SDK also?

because when a User is logged in with Deezer SDK i am not getting notified from the delegate

```
class DeezerSession : NSObject, DeezerSessionDelegate
{


    var DZRReqManager:DZRRequestManager = DZRRequestManager()
    var deezerConnect:DeezerConnect!

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var callbackLogin : (()->())? = nil

    //SHARED INSTANCE
    static var instance: DeezerSession!
    class func sharedInstance() -> DeezerSession {
        if self.instance == nil
        {
            self.instance  = DeezerSession();
        }
        return self.instance
    }

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        self.deezerConnect                  = DeezerConnect(appId: "***" , andDelegate: self )
        self.DZRReqManager.dzrConnect       = self.deezerConnect
        self.deezerConnect.sessionDelegate  = self

        self.retrieveTokenAndExpirationDate()
    }

    // See http://www.deezer.com/fr/developers/simpleapi/permissions
    // for a description of the permissions
    func connectToDeezerWithPermissions()
    {
        print("[DeezerSession] connectToDeezerWithPermissions.")

        //Check if Session still valid update it
        self.deezerConnect.authorize([DeezerConnectPermissionBasicAccess,
                                      DeezerConnectPermissionManageLibrary,
                                      DeezerConnectPermissionOfflineAccess
                                      ])
    }

    func saveToken(token:String,expirationDate:Date,userId:String)
    {
        print("[DeezerSession] Token. \(token) : Saved ")
        print("[DeezerSession] Expire Date after. \(expirationDate) : Saved ")
        print("[DeezerSession] User ID . \(userId) : Saved ")

        defaults.setValue(token, forKey: "DEEZER_TOKEN_KEY")
        defaults.setValue(expirationDate, forKey: "DEEZER_EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY")
        defaults.setValue(userId, forKey: "DEEZER_USER_ID_KEY")
    }

    func deezerSessionDidConnect()
    {


    }

    func retrieveTokenAndExpirationDate()
    {
        self.deezerConnect.accessToken      = defaults.string(forKey: "DEEZER_TOKEN_KEY")
        self.deezerConnect.expirationDate   = defaults.object(forKey: "DEEZER_EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY") as? Date ?? Date()
        self.deezerConnect.userId           = defaults.string(forKey: "DEEZER_USER_ID_KEY")

        print("[DeezerSession] Token. \(self.deezerConnect.accessToken) : Restored ")
        print("[DeezerSession] Expire Date. \(self.deezerConnect.expirationDate) : Restored ")
        print("[DeezerSession] User ID . \(self.deezerConnect.userId) : Restored ")
    }

    func isSessionValid()-> Bool
    {
        print("[DeezerSession] isSessionValid . \(self.deezerConnect.isSessionValid()) ")
        return self.deezerConnect.isSessionValid()
    }


    func deezerDidLogin()
    {
        print("[DeezerSession] deezerDidLogin.")
        self.saveToken(token : self.deezerConnect.accessToken,
                       expirationDate : self.deezerConnect.expirationDate  ,
                       userId : self.deezerConnect.userId)

        if  self.callbackLogin != nil
        {
            self.callbackLogin!()
        }
    }

     func deezerDidNotLogin()-> Bool
    {
        print("[DeezerSession] deezerDidNotLogin.")
        return true
    }

     func deezerDidLogout()
    {
        print("[DeezerSession] deezerDidLogout.")
    }

}
```

all the Delegates are not firing `deezerDidLogout`  `deezerDidNotLogin` `deezerDidLogin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK provides `DeezerSessionDelegate`. Based on the documentation, the `deezerDidLogin` is called when the user successfully logged in.

Hence, you can retrieve from `DeezerConnect` instance the token, the expiration date and the user identifier. You can save them into the Keychain.

The next time the user launches the application, you can set these values back on the `DeezerConnect` instance (retrieving them from the Keychain) and test their validity by sending the -`[DeezerConnect isSessionValid]` message to this same object. If the session is still valid, do not ask the user to log in again.

Obviously the Keychain is the suggested place in order to store the token and the expiration date.

For further info: [iOS Session Management](http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/ios#_session_management)

**Update**

Are you able to modify how you create the singleton instance?

Instead of this code

```
//SHARED INSTANCE
static var instance: DeezerSession!
class func sharedInstance() -> DeezerSession {
    if self.instance == nil
    {
        self.instance  = DeezerSession();
    }
    return self.instance
}
```

just use

```
static let shared = DeezerSession()
```

In fact this is the recommended way to use singleton in Swift.

I think you don't need the `override` in the `init` method as well.

Comment: its not working on swift , only on objective-c, please try the delegate not firing when user login/logout

Comment: @Jack can you elaborate? I cannot understand your question.

Comment: I've converted their SDK from objective-c to Swift , the delegate of userDidLogin is not working on swift code :) go it bro ?

Comment: Why do you need to convert the library in Swift? Can you bridge the library as is?

Comment: @Jack Anyway you should improve your question since it's not possible to understand what you want from it.

Comment: You are right i have bridge the SDK into my swift code , and now the session working fine but when user did login with deezer the delegate userDidLogin() is not firing from Deezer SDK that's the only issue

Comment: @Jack Have you set the delegate correctly? Can you show the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154316/discussion-between-lorenzo-b-and-jack).